# Match housenumbers on buildings (special case of point-in-polygon-test)

Tags: algorithm, indexing, geospatial, openstreetmap, computational-geometry

## Task with example

I'm working with geodata (country-size) from openstreetmap. Buildings are often polygons without housenumbers and a single point with the housenumber is placed within the polygon of the building. Buildings may have multiple housenumbers.

I want to match the housenumbers to the polygons of the buildings.
[image: Example]

## Simple solution

Foreach housenumber perform a point-in-polygon-test with each building-polygon.

## Problem

Way too slow for about 50,000,000 buildings and 10,000,000 address-points.

## Idea

Build and index for the building-polygons to accelerate the search for the surrounding polygon for each housenumber-point.

## Question

What index or strategy would you recommend for this polygon-structure? The polygons never overlap and the area is sparsly covered.

---

*This question is duplicated to gis.stackexchange.com. It was recommendet to post the question there.*

Comment: This question better belongs to http://gis.stackexchange.com. Furthermore you can take a look at the strategies chosen by other [search engines for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines), for example [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

Comment: Should I post a duplicate on gis.stackexachange.com? If not how can I move the question?

Comment: You can't move it as far as I know. Either create a duplicate but mention it in both questions, or close this one.

Comment: use higher datastructures (e.g. quadtree)

Comment: The question is meant to discuss which structure to use (e.g. quadtree, r-tree, ...).

Comment: "Build and index" Typo?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/120347/115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it sounds like you have well-formed polygons to test against, I'd use a spatial hash with a AABB check, and then finally the full point-in-polygon test. Hopefully at that point you'll be averaging three or less point-in-polygon tests per address.

- Break the area your data is over into a simple grid where a grid is a small multiple (2 to 4) of the median building size. (Maybe 100-200 meters?)
- Compute the axis aligned bounding box of every polygon, add it (with its bounding box) to each grid location which the bounding box intersects. (It's pretty simple to figure out where an axis aligned bounding box overlaps regular axis aligned grid cells. I wouldn't store the grid in a simple 2D array -- I'd use a hash table that maps 2D integer grid coordinates, e.g. (1023, 301), to a list of polygons)
- Then go through all your address points. Look up in your hash table what cell that point is in. Go through all the polygons in that cell and if the point is within any polygon's axis aligned bounding box do the full point-in-polygon test.

This has several advantages:

- The data structures are simple -- no fancy libraries needed (other than handling polygons). With C++, your polygon library, and the std namespace this could be implemented in less than an hour.
- Spatial structure isn't hierarchical -- when you're looking up the points you only have to do one O(1) lookup in the hash table.

And of course, the usual disadvantage of grids as a spatial structure:

- Doesn't handle wildly varying sized polygons particularly well. However, I'm hoping since you're using map data the sizes are almost always within an order of magnitude, and probably much less.

Assuming you end up with `N` maximum polygons in each of grid and each polygon has `P` points and you've got `B` buildings and `A` addresses, you're looking at `O(B*P + N*A)`. Since `B` and `P` are likely relatively small, especially on average, you could consider this `O(B + N)` -- pretty much linear.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a 2d-array? Is it to save memory because of the sparseness of the polygons?

Comment: Yes. I would assume that you've got large swaths of countryside and densely packed neighborhoods -- but I admit, I'm biased because that's how it is where I live. Honestly, if you don't think the memory constraints would be a problem, it'd be somewhat simpler to go with the array. But the hash table affords you to be almost boundless -- you don't have to worry about your array size. I'm not sure you'll notice much of a speed difference in any case.

Comment: I thought I'd store it in a 1d-array to gain more speed due to the better cache-efficiency. I'll do some calculations and tests on the memory usage and let you know.

Comment: If you're using a fast language (e.g. C++, D, Fortran, and we'll even count Java, Javascript, and C#) in general you're not going to notice the speed of accessing an array vs a hash table. I can hit a hash table in C# 50 million times in one second. (And that's with some rather complex keys -- not integer pairs.)

Comment: I went with your solution in C# and wrote a class Pixel with X and Y members and overrode the GetHashCode-Method. The rasterization is quite fast, it only take a couple of minutes. Let's see how fast the point-location gets...

Comment: Nice! I was wondering if you were going to go that route, or if you were going to pack the coordinates in a long or ulong and let the default hash method work. ;-)